# Example of Abelian Group of order 2014

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

What are some examples of Abelian Groups of order $2014$ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification

Comment: hint:Why not simply list all of them (up to isomorphism)? It's quite easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2014 = 2 * 19 * 53$

As $2, 19, 53$ are all distinct, there is only one Abelian group of order $2014$ up to isomorphism, which is $\mathbb{Z}_{2014}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{2}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{19}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{53}$.

Also you can proceed this way without using the classification theorem. By [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_theorem_(group_theory)) there are elements of $2, 19, 53$. Suppose they are $a_2,a_{19},a_{53}$. Then $a_2 a_{19} a_{53}$ generates a subgroup of $2014$ (which must be itself):

if $(a_2 a_{19} a_{53})^n = a_2^{n\mod 2} a_{19}^{n\mod 19} a_{53}^{n\mod 53} = e$, we must have $2014|n$, otherwise some of the exponents would not nonzero. Say it's that of $a_2$, then $a_2^{n \times 19 \times 53\mod 2} = e$, which is a contradiction.